# Bigquery: convert abbreviated month string to number

Tags: google-bigquery

In Bigquery:

How do you convert an abbreviated month into month's number?

input could be: 01-feb-1980 or 01-Feb-1980 or 01-FEB-1980
output: 02

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is pure Standard SQL solution which doesn't require UDFs, and relies on [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#parse_date) function, particularly on [%b format specifier](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#supported-format-elements-for-date):

```
select extract(month from parse_date('%d-%b-%Y', d)) from
unnest(['01-FEB-1980', '01-feb-1980', '01-Feb-1980']) d
```

returns `2, 2, 2`

Comment: i clearly see now what is `over-engineering` mean! :o) thank you Mosha! still love experimenting :o)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes date integrations can be tricky when they are not in standard formatting.

This is one of those cases, where date's month comes as something like 01-Feb-1980 or 01-FEB-1980 or 01-feb-1980

```
select 
month_str as month_abbriviation,
(case 
when upper(month_str) = 'JAN' then '01' 
when upper(month_str) = 'FEB' then '02' 
when upper(month_str) = 'MAR' then '03' 
when upper(month_str) = 'APR' then '04' 
when upper(month_str) = 'MAY' then '05' 
when upper(month_str) = 'JUN' then '06' 
when upper(month_str) = 'JUL' then '07' 
when upper(month_str) = 'AUG' then '08' 
when upper(month_str) = 'SEP' then '09' 
when upper(month_str) = 'OCT' then '10' 
when upper(month_str) = 'NOV' then '11' 
when upper(month_str) = 'DEC' then '12' 
end) as month_number
from (select regexp_extract('01-Feb-1980', r'..-(...)-....') as month_str);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL has nice feature called [Scalar UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions)
Two languages supported so far - [JavaScript UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions#supported-udf-languages) and [SQL UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions#sql-udf-structure)

Below example helps in a sense of cleaning main code by extracting transformation logic outside main query, so code gets better/easier readable and maintained (*definitely matter of personal preferences*)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION MONTH_STRING(x STRING)
RETURNS STRING AS (LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(x, r'-(...)-')));

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION MONTH_TO_NUMBER(x STRING)
RETURNS STRING AS (CASE 
  WHEN x='jan' THEN '01' WHEN x='feb' THEN '02' WHEN x='mar' THEN '03' WHEN x='apr' THEN '04' 
  WHEN x='may' THEN '05' WHEN x='jun' THEN '06' WHEN x='jul' THEN '07' WHEN x='aug' THEN '08' 
  WHEN x='sep' THEN '09' WHEN x='oct' THEN '10' WHEN x='nov' THEN '11' WHEN x='dec' THEN '12' 
END );

WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT '1-feb-1980'AS dt UNION ALL
  SELECT '01-Mar-1980' AS dt UNION ALL
  SELECT '01-SEP-1980' AS dt
)
SELECT 
  dt, 
  MONTH_TO_NUMBER(MONTH_STRING(dt)) AS month_number
FROM yourTable
```

> Option 2

Somehow i didn't like MONTH_TO_NUMBER() function because of its heaviness with `WHEN THEN` things

Below version of this function looks more elegant to me (*not really sure honestly - still looks heavy - but I love experimenting anyway*)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION MONTH_TO_NUMBER(x STRING)
RETURNS STRING AS ((
  SELECT SUBSTR(CAST(101 + num AS STRING), 2) FROM  
  UNNEST(['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']) AS list 
  WITH OFFSET AS num WHERE list = x));
```

> Option 3

back to all inline without UDF

```
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT '1-feb-1980'AS dt UNION ALL
  SELECT '01-Mar-1980' AS dt UNION ALL
  SELECT '01-SEP-1980' AS dt
)
SELECT 
  dt,
  (SELECT SUBSTR(CAST(101 + num AS STRING), 2) 
   FROM UNNEST(['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']) AS list 
   WITH OFFSET AS num 
   WHERE list = LOWER(REGEXP_EXTRACT(dt, r'-(...)-'))) AS month_number
FROM yourTable
```